# how to correct a mistake from two dimensional matrix using matlab programming

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Based on data (e.g. gender,age and handedness) of 8 participants of an experiment I am required to store the information in a 2-dimensional matrix using MATLAB Programming and correct a “*mistake*” by changing the handedness of two participants. Say:

```
% id, gender, age, handedness
participants = [1 1 21 1; 
                2 2 25 1;
                3 2 19 1;
                4 2 23 2; 
                5 1 23 1].
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: your example contains 5 participants right? also what do you mean by correcting a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're showing a 5x4 matrix:

```
% id, gender, age, handedness
participants = [1 1 21 1; 
                2 2 25 1;
                3 2 19 1;
                4 2 23 2; 
                5 1 23 1];
```

In Matlab you can access cells in a matrix with the `()` operator. In your case your 2D matrix  you have `(row,column)`. E.g. the age of the second participant would be

```
display(participants(2,3)); % 25
```

You can show all rows or columns with `:` e.g.

```
display(participants(2,:)); % 2 2 25 1
```

will display all information for the second participant whereas

```
display(participants(:,3)); % 21; 25; 19; 23; 23
```

will display the third column "age".

If you want to modify a cell you can do it like this:

```
participants(2,3) = 99
```

This would change the age of the second participant to `99`.

hth

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, probably what you want to do is to estimate (e.g., with `OLS`) the `handedness` as a function of the other two variables and project on the fitted hyperplane, to find the `handedness` values that gives the largest errors. We can do the same with the following:

```
X = participants(:,2:3); % explanatory variables or regressors
y = participants(:,4); % the dependent variable handedness
w = inv(X'*X)*(X'*y); % weights learnt for OLS
y_hat = X*w % predicted handness
% 0.97038
% 1.41533
% 1.22988
% 1.35351
% 1.03220
e = abs(y - X*w) % errors in prediction
% 0.029620
% 0.415325
% 0.229878
% 0.646491
% 0.032196
```

As we can see, the two handedness values with maximum errors (mistakes) are the 2nd and the 4th value, which are respectively 1 and 2 in the sample data. So they are the ones with maximum mistakes and can be corrected.